# Entity Framwork Mapping One-To-One Aspnet_Membership Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using EF5 with the default aspnet_Membership Schema.

I have a custom User object with a foreign key referencing the aspnet_Membership table.

The foreign key in the User object is called 'AspnetID'

I need to map this one-to-one relationship with the fluent API but I am having no luck

Objects look like this:

```
public class aspnet_Membership
{
    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public aspnet_Users aspnet_User { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Guid AspnetID { get; set; } //This is the foreign key referencing aspnet_Membership

    public virtual aspnet_Membership Aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(u => u.Aspnet_Membership).WithOptional(u => u.User);
```

But I know that I need to map the foreign key name some how...Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WithRequiredPricipal() instead of WithOptional()

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Aspnet_Membership)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.User);
```

Comment: I still get this error at runtime: Invalid column name 'User_UserID

Comment: I need to Map AspnetID in the User object to the UserID property in aspnet_Membership. Should EF infer this relationship based on the foreign key constraint on the Users table?

Comment: Also, every aspnet_Membership object does not HAVE to be associated with a User object, which this solution seems to imply...unless I am missing something.  BUT Every User does require an aspnet_Membership relationship